# gitlab-runner x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: openssl, certificate, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to register a new runner on gitlab following these steps :
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html

But when I enter the url, token and tags, an error message pops-up saying:

> ERROR: Registering runner... failed           runner=CS-XXX status=couldn't execute POST against https://example.com/api/v4/runners: Post https://example.com/api/v4/runners: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

I'm working on a new server and already installed the gitlab-runner.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you need to use `tls-ca-file` option during registration or in the configuration of your runner.

Here is an example of [non-interactive](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/#one-line-registration-command) registration with `tls-ca-file` option :

```
gitlab-runner register \
      --non-interactive \
      --registration-token YOUTOKEN \
      --url https://example.com/ \
      --tls-ca-file /path/to/your/ca.crt
```

Other way, you can [refer](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section) the `tls-ca-file` option in your `config.toml` under the `[[runners]]` section

more info : https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/tls-self-signed.html

Comment: Can I disable TLS for gitlab runner and gitlab ? I use external reverse-proxy to secure Letsencrypt TLS. Meanwhile runner communicates to gitlab through encrypted docker network. http-only is more than enough.

Comment: yes, you can, but the risk in this case is of some malicious code be able to capture the traffic on the host or inside some container and be able to visualize sensitive info passing thru.