# gitlab runner - x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: ssl, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Well, I am trying to run gitlab-runner on my PC, which should be connected to our Gitlab on the server.

I am getting

```
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=XXXXXX status=couldn't execute POST against https://XXXXXXXXXX/api/v4/runners: Post https://XXXXXXXXXX/api/v4/runners: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems
```

I ran through different advices, but nothing really changed.

My current setup is self-signed ceritificate generated by

```
wget "https://letsencrypt.org/certs/lets-encrypt-x3-cross-signed.pem.txt" -O "/Users/admin/gitlab-runner-certs/fs-tul-letsencrypt.pem"
```

(I also tried https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-run-gitlab-with-self-signed-ssl-certificate),

script for gitlab-runner registration

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# tried also without sudo
sudo gitlab-runner register \
      --non-interactive \
      --registration-token OUR_GITLAB_TOKEN \
      --url OUR_GITLAB_HOST_URL \
      --tls-ca-file /Users/admin/gitlab-runner-certs/fs-tul-letsencrypt.pem \
      --executor docker
```

And I am still getting that error. Any idea?

I also did not change anything on server side. Shouldn't I do anything there? (I did not find any mention about it, but still asking)

PS: [gitlab-runner x509: certificate signed by unknown authority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55622960/gitlab-runner-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority) did not fix my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem on server side where gitlab was running.
There was wrong path to full-chain certificate.