# x509: certificate signed by unknown authority problem when registering a runner even with self-certificate

Tags: ssl, gitlab, ssl-certificate, gitlab-ci-runner, self-signed-certificate

I have a server running on linux OS. Docker is installed along with a container on which gitlab is installed too. Everything is working fine. I intend to install and register a runner on a windows 10 to use through my CI CD process (the reason is that I have multiple projects in .NET needed to be complied and build during the deployment time therefore I have decided to place them on windows and by registering a runner in Shell could run a batch script file to build those projects).
When I am going to register the runner I am getting this error :
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
which it has been explained how to solve it (gitlab doc) through creating a ssl self certificate.
after so much efforts I am still getting this error.  I am a little bit new with ssl but I follow this way:
first I created a self certificate with this commad on my gitlab container:
https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/gitlab/administration/create-ssl-certificate-nginx/
then, I use this file on windows to register the gitlab runner. But error is still thrown during registration.
When I use the following command on windows to verify the self certificate:

```
echo | openssl s_client -CAfile /etc/gitlab-runner/certs/gitlab-hostname.tld.crt -connect gitlab-hostname.tld:443
```

I run into this error in the last lines:

```
read R BLOCK
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 01 Jul 2020 07:58:52 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 150
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

read:errno=0
```

can anyone provide some steps in details to solve this problem? I was in searching for a right and applicable answer but no result was achieved yet.
PS: [gitlab-runner x509: certificate signed by unknown authority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55622960/gitlab-runner-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority) did not fix my problem