# Does my private server hosting GitLab need a valid CA certificate to register a runner on a separate server?

Tags: ssl, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I've been at this for a few days now with no luck.  After traversing a plethora of GitLab documentation, whenever I try to register a runner on a server in my network (besides the server hosting GitLab), I receive this error:

```
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 
runner=xxxxxxxx status=couldn't execute POST against https://gitlab_instance_url.com/api/v4/runners: 
Post https://gitlab_instance_url.com/api/v4/runners: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
PANIC: Failed to register the runner. You may be having network problems.
```

I have tried:

- Creating private and public keys, a CSR, and getting a CA-signed certificate for the server I'm trying to register my runner on
- Registering the runner using `--tls-ca-file=path/to/cert`
- Creating a new server from scratch to register the runner
- Creating a runner *on the server GitLab is hosted on* (this is the only one that works, but it defeats the purpose because I need to connect my CI/CD pipeline with a server other than the one hosting GitLab)

Other important detail:

- I am *not* using Docker or Kubernetes, just vanilla GitLab Runner

Resources used:

- [gitlab-runner x509: certificate signed by unknown authority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55622960/gitlab-runner-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority)
- https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/runners.html#register-a-new-runner
- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab-runner/-/issues/81#note_252326958
- https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/tls-self-signed.html
- https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html
- https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html#using-debrpm-package

The only thing I can think of is that the server hosting GitLab has *an expired CA certificate*, even though the GitLab URL *does* have a valid certificate.  Perhaps the reason I keep getting `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` is because the server taking the requests has an expired certificate, and it halts the registration there.  Does anyone know if this is the case, or could it be something else?  I'm seriously running out of ideas.

**Edit: The problem is not fixed, but it turns out I was mistaken and the server hosting GitLab did have a valid certificate, and I was able to create a runner with no issues on a different server, but not the server I spun up and added a CA certificate to.  This leads me to believe that the server I spun up has some issue with certificate configuration.  Currently investigating this.**

Comment: A few suggestions:
- use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to check for errors in the SSL setup (e.g. incomplete chain)
- check the "runner" machine, are OS and gitlab-runner up to date? Maybe the CA of your certificate really is unknown to that machine.

Comment: Due to security policies, I'm currently unable to use that service, however the runner machine OS and gitlab-runner are both up to date, so my best guess is that I must have configured the certificate improperly, so I'm going back to see what I might have missed.